# Exception "an item with the same key has already been added" for Remoted Generic Component

Tags: castle-windsor, ioc-container, microkernel

For various reasons I am trying to upgrade a project from an old version of Castle to v 2.5.3 (I cannot move to v3 due to breaking changes) and am encountering an issue with a generic component that is remoted:

```
   Container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IStore<>))
        .Named("GenericStore")
        .AddAttributeDescriptor("remoteserver", "RecoverableComponent")
        .AddAttributeDescriptor("marshalByRefProxy", "true")
        .ImplementedBy(typeof(MyStore<>)));
```

The component appears to register OK, but at the point I attempt to resolve:

```
   Container.Resolve<IStore<Users>>()
```

I get an exception "an item with the same key has already been added" and the stack trace (shortened):

```
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.System.Collections.IDictionary.Add(Object key, Object value)
at Castle.Facilities.Remoting.RemotingInspector.ConfigureServerComponent(RemotingStrategy server, Type type, ComponentModel model)
at Castle.Facilities.Remoting.RemotingInspector.ProcessModel(IKernel kernel, ComponentModel model)
at Castle.MicroKernel.ModelBuilder.DefaultComponentModelBuilder.BuildModel(String key, Type service, Type classType, IDictionary extendedProperties)
at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultGenericHandler.GetSubHandler(CreationContext context, Type genericType)
at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultGenericHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired)
at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.AbstractHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context, Boolean instanceRequired)
at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.AbstractHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context)
```

As you can see from the stack trace, it appears to be "building the model" (call to DefaultComponentModelBuilder) again.

**Am I registering my component incorrectly?**

I've downloaded some of the source code to try and find what I am doing wrong, but wonder if it is actually an issue caused by a combination of Generic and Remoting?

The exception is caused by *Castle.Facilities.Remoting.RemotingInspector* trying to add properties to the ExtendedProperties dictionary that alreadt exist. In *Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultGenericHander* it doesn't appear to be detecting the fact that the model already exists (is it me or is nothing ever actually added to the Dictionary *type2SubHandler*?).

**Can anyone tell me if I am doing anything wrong, or is there actually a bug?**

Comment: ddi you ever fix this? I'm getting a similar error

Comment: Not really, but I am pretty sure that the only solution I found was to register each one explicitly so `Component.For(typeof(IStore<User>)` rather than `Component.For(typeof(IStore<>)`.  It appeared that Castle had a problem with resolving for something without explicit generic type parameters.

Comment: I think mine was because I had registered one service alone then had the service forwarded in another config so basically could be seen as re-registering it? Not sure... Still looking into it

Comment: Are you upgrading?  And which version - 2.5.3 or 3?

Answer (score 3):

My humble suggestion is that it is not a problem with Castle Windsor at all. Probably you have a static dictionary defined in the component that Castle Windsor tries to resolve which dictionary(or other collection with uniqe key constraint) has a diplicate key. Probably from copy-paste operation. you will get this error if you try to instantiate the class by hand. The code may look like this :

```
public class MissTypedDictionaryClass
{
... some ctors here
... some other methods and props

... and somewhere here lies the mistyped dict
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> MyDeclaredDict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"Key1", "Val1"},
        {"Key2", "Val2"},
        {"Key1", "Val3"}, // Here is the problem.
    };
 }
```